# android how to get the current touch positon

Tags: android, touch-event

How do I get the current touch coordinates?

In my case, I'm setting a timer and want to see if there was any movement during the elapsed time.  When receiving a MotionEvent, it's easy enough to cache the x & y coordinates from the event.  As long as more touch events come, it's easy to cache the latest touch coordinates.  Then, finally, compare the most recent to the originals.

But this technique fails because, sometimes, some other view consumes future touch events and my view no longer gets them (it gets a "cancel").  Thus, the most recent cached value is "stale".

The obvious solution is to somehow query the system to get the current touch coordinates (or none if he user let go).  So far, I haven't found any such method.

Comment: Have you tried the onTouchEvent for the Activity? I'd go for that, the highest-level available method to intercept touch events. Then track them as you'd like.

Comment: No go.  Touch events don't even make to the activity - they're consumed by one of the views.

Comment: If the touch events aren't going to the activity, they aren't even going to your app, they're probably going to another app, which makes sense why you can't get them. Also, what do you mean by "other views"?

Comment: "other" - any other view in the activity.  It can be a child view, such as an EditText, or it can be a parent view, such as a ViewPager.  Also, to clarify, my app is receiving plenty of touch events - I've placed Log traces to verify.

Comment: Actually, EditText is not consuming the clicks - the parent still sees them.  My higher level window does, though.  So, my hypothetical solution might work after all.  I'll have to give it some more time and see what crops up.

Comment: If these solutions don't work, I propose a hack: nest your layout in a FrameLayout and add a View to the root to cover the entire screen. Then use that View to intercept ALL touch events, log them, and let them through.

Comment: That sounds good, @Tom, but I think "intercept" only works until a view returns "true" to onTouchEvent.  I think what intercept does is to give the parent view a chance to handle the event *before* the child does, but not to unconditionally intercept.

Comment: I was under the impression that you didn't want to consume the touch events, you just wanted to log them. Either way, this should work for either.

Comment: @Tom, that is correct - in the view where I'm determining whether there is touch movement, I do not want to consume the touch events.  But I have no control over what the child views do.  If they consume the touch events, my view won't get them.